# Android Value ... of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray

Tags: android, json, wcf, arrays

My project having a WCF to get records from database and return in JSON format like this:

```
{"GetNotesResult":"[{\"ID\":1,\"Title\":\"Note 1\",\"Content\":\"Hello Vu Chien Thang\",\"CreatedBy\":\"thangvc\"},{\"ID\":2,\"Title\":\"Note 2\",\"Content\":\"Hello Nguyen Thi Ngoc\",\"CreatedBy\":\"thangvc\"}]"}
```

I also have a android app to consume the JSON and this is my code:

```
private JSONArray getNotes(String UserName, String Password) {
        JSONArray jarray = null;
        JSONObject jobj = null;
        try{
            StringBuilder builder = new StringBuilder(URL);
            builder.append("UserName=" + loggedInUser.getUserName());
            builder.append("&");
            builder.append("Password=" + loggedInUser.getPassword());

            HttpClient client = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet httpGet = new HttpGet(builder.toString());
            HttpResponse response = client.execute(httpGet);

            int status = response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode();

            if(status==200)
            {
                HttpEntity entity = response.getEntity();
                String data = EntityUtils.toString(entity,"utf-8");
                jobj = new JSONObject(data);
                jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("GetNotesResult");
            }
            else
            {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Error", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }
        catch(ClientProtocolException e)
        {
            Log.d("ClientProtocol",e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(IOException e)
        {
            Log.d("IOException", e.getMessage());
        }
        catch(JSONException e)
        {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }
        catch(Exception e)
        {
            Log.d("Unhandle Error", e.getMessage());
        }
        return jarray;
    }
```

I set breakpoint at `jarray = jobj.getJSONArray("GetNotesResult");` and get this message from `JSONException`:

```
Value [{"ID":1,"Title":"Note 1","Content":"Hello Vu Chien Thang","CreatedBy":"thangvc"},{"ID":2,"Title":"Note 2","Content":"Hello Nguyen Thi Ngoc","CreatedBy":"thangvc"}] at GetNotesResult of type java.lang.String cannot be converted to JSONArray
```

I tried to copy JSON string and paste to an online JSON parser website at http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and it parsed well. Please help me to solve this problem!

Comment: That is not correct JsonArray

Comment: Of course I already added INTERNET permssion to manifest file. I even logged in to my android application with another function to connect with server

Comment: Dear Sameer, I use LINQtoSQL DataContext and JavaScriptSerializer to serialize the result and that is raw JSON I get from browser, could you tell me more about the problem of JSON format?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

In your json the value of `GetNotesResult` is inclused inside `""` so it's considered a string not an array..

to be parsed as an array it should be..

```
{"GetNotesResult":[{\"ID\":1,\"Title\":\"Note 1\",\"Content\":\"Hello Vu Chien Thang\",\"CreatedBy\":\"thangvc\"},{\"ID\":2,\"Title\":\"Note 2\",\"Content\":\"Hello Nguyen Thi Ngoc\",\"CreatedBy\":\"thangvc\"}]}
```

So the solution is one of two things:

1. If you can modify the server response, remove the `""` from arround the json array.
   or
2. parse it first as string and then create a json array from that string..

   ```
   String notes = jobj.getString("GetNotesResult");
   jarray = new JSONArray(notes);
   ```

Comment: the `\"` also will not parse. See my answer.

Comment: exactly what i want.Thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 0):

I tried pasting it into http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/ and it did not work.

to make it work I had to replace all the `\"` to `"` and then remove the `"` symbol from before the `[` and after the `]`

like this:

```
{"GetNotesResult":[{"ID":1,"Title":"Note1","Content":"HelloVuChienThang","CreatedBy":"thangvc"},{"ID":2,"Title":"Note2","Content":"HelloNguyenThiNgoc","CreatedBy":"thangvc"}]}
```

Comment: I'm not just paste the JSON I got in browser. I copied the value I got in JSONException that I mentioned above in my code and paste to  http://jsonviewer.stack.hu/.